# TextView with a specific item from a array using Day of the Month

Tags: javascript, android, textview, android-calendar

I'm new with this things, I need to do a app that show the user a unique phrase each day of the month, like today is 25, the textView should show "A potato." Tomorrow the textView should show "A carrot." and the next month, day 25, show the same potato one, and day 26 show the same carrot one.

This is my code:

When I start it on my phone, it does nothing.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  String q;
  Resources con;
  TextView frase1;
  TextView frase2;
  TextView frase3;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    frase1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    frase2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    frase3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView3);

    con = getResources();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    if (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH == 1){
        q = con.getStringArray(R.array.dia)[1];
        frase1.setText(q);
    }
    if (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH == 2){
        q = con.getStringArray(R.array.dia)[2];
        frase1.setText(q);
    }
    if (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH == 3){
        q = con.getStringArray(R.array.dia)[3];
        frase1.setText(q);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you facing ?

Comment: Shouldn't you use "if (day == 1)" instead of "if (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH == 1)" ??

Comment: Sachin, when I load the app, the textview that should appear the phrases, shows nothing.

Comment: Just tried switching to day, but nothing. EDIT : WORKED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are entering none of the `if statement` and thus nothing is being set to `TextView`. Try using an `else statement` like below. Try this -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
            String q;
            Resources con;
            TextView frase1;
            TextView frase2;
            TextView frase3;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     frase1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    frase2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    frase3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView3);

    con = getResources();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    if (day == 1){
        q = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dia)[1];
        frase1.setText(q);
    }
    else if (day == 2){
        q = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dia)[2];
        frase1.setText(q);
    }
    else if (day == 3){
        q = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dia)[3];
        frase1.setText(q);
    } else {
        q = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dia)[3];
            frase1.setText(q);
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

this doesnt answser your question, but you can replace all ifs with frase1.setText(con.getStringArray(R.array.dia)[day]);

Also, try using logs to find which value creates the problem (for example, Log.i(TAG,day);)